# Array interpreted as a Fixnum

Tags: arrays, ruby, fixnum

I'm currently learning ruby and I wrote this piece of code :

```
def multi_gen
  s = []
  for i in (3..10)
    if i%3 == 0 || i%5 == 0
      s<<i
    end
  end
  return s
end

puts multi_gen

def rec_sum(num_arr)
  if num_arr == []
    return 0
  else
    num_arr.first + rec_sum(num_arr.shift)
  end
end

puts rec_sum(multi_gen)
```

That should return the sum of all 3 and 5 multiples up to 1000.

But I get an error :

```
myrbfile.rb:17:in `rec_sum': undefined method `first' for 3:Fixnum (NoMethodError)
        from villani.rb:17:in `rec_sum'
        from villani.rb:21:in `<main>'
```

But when I re-write it like this :

```
def multi_gen
  s = []
  for i in (3..10)
    if i%3 == 0 || i%5 == 0
      s<<i
    end
  end
  return s
end

puts multi_gen

def rec_sum(num_arr)
  if num_arr == []
    return 0
  else
    num_arr[0] + rec_sum(num_arr[1..num_arr.last])
  end
end

puts rec_sum(multi_gen)
```

I don't get the error.

So why is my first rec_sum functions interpretting my Array as a Fixnum in the first case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mudasobwa [already explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49748260/477037) why using `shift` doesn't give the expected result. Apart from that, your code is somehow unidiomatic.

In `multi_gen` you are creating an empty array and append elements to it using a `for` loop. You rarely have to populate an array manually. Instead, you can usually use one of Ruby's `Array` or `Enumerable` methods to generate the array. [`select`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Array.html#method-i-select) is a very common one – it returns an array containing the elements for which the given block returns `true`:

```
(1..1000).select { |i| i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0 }
#=> [3, 5, 6, 9, 10, 12, ...]
```

In `rec_sum`, you check `if num_arr == []`. Although this works, you are creating an empty throw-away array. To determine whether an array is empty, you should call its [`empty?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Array.html#method-i-empty-3F):

```
if num_arr.empty?
  # ...
end
```

To get the remaining elements from the array, you use:

```
num_arr[1..num_arr.last]
```

which can be abbreviated by passing a negative index to [`[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D):

```
num_arr[1..-1]
```

There's also [`drop`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Array.html#method-i-drop) which might look a little nicer:

```
num_arr[0] + rec_sum(num_arr[1..-1])
# vs
num_arr.first + rec_sum(num_arr.drop(1))
```

Another option to get first and remaining elements from an array is Ruby's [array decomposition](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Array+Decomposition) feature (note the `*`):

```
def rec_sum(num_arr)
  if num_arr.empty?
    0
  else
    first, *remaining = num_arr
    first + rec_sum(remaining)
  end
end
```

You could also consider using a [guard clause](http://wiki.c2.com/?GuardClause) to return from the method early:

```
def rec_sum(num_arr)
  return 0 if num_arr.empty?
  first, *remaining = num_arr
  first + rec_sum(remaining)
end
```

Writing recursive methods is great for learning purposed, but Ruby also has a built-in [`sum`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Array.html#method-i-sum) method:

```
multi_gen.sum #=> 234168
```

or – since you are using an older Ruby version – [`inject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject):

```
multi_gen.inject(0, :+) #=> 234168
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! 

I understand now, and I'll try to improve my syntax and start using more Ruby features :)

Comment: @SuperTotoGo you're welcome, but you should give mudasobwa the green tick. My answer was meant more as an addition.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is in the recursive call:

```
rec_sum(num_arr.shift)
```

[`Array#shift`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-shift) returns *the shifted element*, not the remaining array. You should explicitly pass the array as an argument to recursive call:

```
rec_sum(num_arr[1..-1])
```

or

```
rec_sum(num_arr.tap(&:shift))
```

The latter would [likely] be looking too cumbersome for the beginner, but it’s a very common rubyish approach: [`Object#tap`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-tap) yields the receiver to the block, returning the receiver. Inside a block (`num_arr.tap(&:shift)` is a shorthand for `num_arr.tap { |a| a.shift }` we mutate the array by shifting the element out, and it’s being returned as a result.

Comment: _"we mutate the array"_ – I don't think we want to do that. At least not the original one.

Comment: @Stefan initially there was `shift` in the OP, I just reproduced the expected behaviour.

Comment: Looking at the second (working) implementation in the OP, I think the side effect introduced by `shift` was unintended.